# How to delete inserted <span> on backspace?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

Use case: I build a custom Acronym plugin for CKEditor. So user can either insert an acronym via dialog popup or select a text and convert it to acronym. In either case, I am adding a `<span>` for some custom styling and manipulation.

Something like this `<span class="acronym">test</span>`

Issue: In the editor after I insert an acronym. If I use backspace to delete, say I delete the closing `</span>` and start to type again. Everything get added to the acronym span.

Something like this `<span class="acronym">test typing something`

I am creating span as per [CKEditor](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.element) so its adding a closing `</span>` even if I delete it. So the cursor stay inside the span.

Is there a way to detect and delete the entire acronym span. if, either opening or closing span is deleted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logic I used: On backspace key press, get the current element selected under cursor and check if its acronym element. If yes, delete.

```
 $('html').keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 8) {
       var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editable,
       sel = editor.getSelection();
       var ele = sel.getStartElement();
       if(ele.getAttribute( 'class' ) == 'acronym'){
          ele.remove();
       }
    }
 });
```

I can't use the placeholder plugin of CKEditor, as explained in the comment below.

Exploring for other options. Until then, accepting this as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Placeholder plugin](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/placeholder.html). It's based on the [widget system](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_widgets) and you can easily [build your own widget](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/widget_sdk_intro) which will represent acronyms.

Comment: Thanks @Reinmar for your note. I can't use placeholder plugin.Because, I should be able to convert a selected text to Acronym too. So, I implemented the following logic. On backspace key press, I get the current DOM and check if its acronym DOM, if yes, I delete it. I am yet to look into CKEDitor widgets SDK.